# Javascript - page with 30+ embedded youtube videos - load iframe on click

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to ask for help. I have web page with 30+ videos embedded from youtube. I would like to show 1-2 videos and the rest load when user click on button.

Currently, embedded videos are hidden but I have a feeling they are also loading in the background.

What is the best way to show video and load from Youtube after a click on the button?

My current code:

```
<center>
<button onclick="myFunction('kataguruma')" class="myButton">Show Kata-guruma</button> <br><br></center>
<p> </p>
<div id="kataguruma" style="display: none;">
<center>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrE62Dzg4oM" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
</center>
</div>

<script>// <![CDATA[
function myFunction(el) {
  var x = document.getElementById(el);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// ]]></script>
```

Comment: Create the elements but populate the src later with your event.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I am understanding your question correctly hence correct me if I am wrong.
Assuming that you want to play the video when user clicked it . Just remove the `allow= "autoplay"`

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrE62Dzg4oM" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0">
```

If you want the video to autoplay it by itself when the page is loaded you will need to add back not only `allow="autoplay"`, you will also need to add `?autoplay=1` at the end of your embedded link source like this.

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrE62Dzg4oM?autoplay=1" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0">
```

If you are looking to only load and insert the iframe when the user pressed the button. You can find the sample code below to see whether it answers your question.

```js
//list of links 
let links = new Array ("https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrE62Dzg4oM",
                        "https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrE62Dzg4oM");

function myFunction(el) {
  var x = document.getElementById(el);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";

    //loop through all the link which are in the list 
    for(i = 0 ; i < links.length ; i++){
    var ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifrm.setAttribute('id', "ifrm"+i ); // assign an id

    // assign url
    ifrm.setAttribute('src', links[i]);
    ifrm.setAttribute('width', '560');
    ifrm.setAttribute('height', '315');
    // Append the iframe to the div
    document.getElementById("kataguruma").appendChild(ifrm);
    }
    
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    // remove all the iframes in the div when the button is pressed again 
    var node = document.getElementById('kataguruma');
    node.innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
<button onclick="myFunction('kataguruma')" class="myButton">Show Kata-guruma</button> <br><br></center>
<p> </p>
 <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrE62Dzg4oM" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" style="">
</iframe>

 <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YrE62Dzg4oM" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" style="">
</iframe>

<div id="kataguruma" style="display: none;">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Tan Yi Jing for your reply. The whole idea is load the page as fast as possible. I understand (maybe I am wrong) that the iframe goes to the source and pulls some data. But I want this behaving only for 2 videos. The rest will load after user clicks on a button. By default videos are "display: none"

Comment: Hi, I already edit my answer above. The iframe will only be generated and loaded from an array that is stored in the JS when the user pressed the button. If you want to have 30 videos, just add 30 links to the array. If this solves your question, you can mark my answer as correct.